# np.genfromtxt won't make a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a csv file which contains:

```
0812,EP2463,R,FEIGE
0812,EP2466,R,FEIGE
0816,EP2462,R,FEIGE
0816,EP2460,R,FEIGE
```

I need to convert this to a 2D array of strings. When I try

```
data = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=',', dtype=None)
```

I get a 1D array

```
[['\xef\xbb\xbf0812' 'EP2463 'R' 'FEIGE']
 ['0812' 'EP2466' 'R' 'FEIGE']
 ['0816' 'EP2462' 'R' 'FEIGE']
 ['0816' 'EP2460' 'R' 'FEIGE']]
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: That's a 2d array.  What's the encoding of this array?  I suspect there are some initial characters that read as ''\xef\xbb\xbf'.

Comment: Is this Python2?  What `numpy` version?

Comment: The extra characters are the UTF8 BOM that windows editors add at the start of the file.

Comment: Did one of the below solutions work? Feel free to accept one, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

In a PY3 (ipython) session with numpy 1.14, and a file written as UTF8 with BOM (in Linux):

```
In [166]: np.genfromtxt('stack49969840.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None,encoding='utf8')
Out[166]: 
array([['\ufeff0812', 'EP2463', 'R', 'FEIGE'],
       ['0812', 'EP2466', 'R', 'FEIGE'],
       ['0816', 'EP2462', 'R', 'FEIGE'],
       ['0816', 'EP2460', 'R', 'FEIGE']], dtype='<U6')

In [167]: np.genfromtxt('stack49969840.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None,encoding='utf-8-sig')
Out[167]: 
array([(812, 'EP2463', 'R', 'FEIGE'), (812, 'EP2466', 'R', 'FEIGE'),
       (816, 'EP2462', 'R', 'FEIGE'), (816, 'EP2460', 'R', 'FEIGE')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<U6'), ('f2', '<U1'), ('f3', '<U5')])
```

With `dtype=None`, and ignoring the BOM, this array is 1d with a structured (compound) dtype.  That is, it deduces that the first column can be read as integers.

Loading as string, gives a 2d string dtype (here unicode, but it could be bytestring):

```
In [169]: np.genfromtxt('stack49969840.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=str,encoding='utf-8-sig')
Out[169]: 
array([['0812', 'EP2463', 'R', 'FEIGE'],
       ['0812', 'EP2466', 'R', 'FEIGE'],
       ['0816', 'EP2462', 'R', 'FEIGE'],
       ['0816', 'EP2460', 'R', 'FEIGE']], dtype='<U6')
```

The same file, read in binary mode is:

```
In [8]: open('stack49969840.txt',mode='rb').read()
Out[8]: b'\xef\xbb\xbf0812,EP2463,R,FEIGE\n0812,EP2466,R,FEIGE\n0816,EP2462,R,FEIGE\n0816,EP2460,R,FEIGE\n'
```

with your extra string:

Your extra string is

```
In [168]: print('\xef\xbb\xbf')
ï»¿
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`, which has more in-built functionality:

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""0812,EP2463,R,FEIGE
0812,EP2466,R,FEIGE
0816,EP2462,R,FEIGE
0816,EP2460,R,FEIGE""")

# replace mystr with 'data.csv'
res = pd.read_csv(mystr, header=None, dtype=object).values.astype(str)
```

Result:

```
array([['0812', 'EP2463', 'R', 'FEIGE'],
       ['0812', 'EP2466', 'R', 'FEIGE'],
       ['0816', 'EP2462', 'R', 'FEIGE'],
       ['0816', 'EP2460', 'R', 'FEIGE']],
      dtype='<U6')
```